# Facebook: get event information for public page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

My Facebook page publishes public events and I am developing an app that uses this page. I want to get the number of interested/going people for a specific event given its Facebook id.

I, the creator of the app, am also the admin of the page. However, using my app access token that I generated with the app id and the app secret, I can't call the event API: `https://graph.facebook.com/v3.0/137340177139954?access_token={access_token}`

I get the following error

```
{
    "error": {
        "message": "Unsupported get request. Object with ID '137340177139954' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api",
        "type": "GraphMethodException",
        "code": 100,
        "error_subcode": 33,
        "fbtrace_id": "FqJ5oAqdukA"
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? How do I get event information about a page that I own

Comment: You use your page admin user token, or a page token. With just your app token, the API doesn’t know that you have the right to access this.

Answer (score 0):

The endpoint that you're hitting is not correct. You're forgetting the `/events` portion after your `page_id`.

This is what it should look like:

`https://graph.facebook.com/v3.0/137340177139954/events?access_token={access_token}`